# Kotlin - Conditional method name with same parameters (mitigation of code duplication)

Tags: kotlin

Let's consider this code examples in Kotlin:

```kotlin
if (isFooBar)
    method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
else
    method2(arg1, arg2, arg3)

// Or larger example
when(enumBar) {
    VALUE_A -> method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    VALUE_B -> method2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    VALUE_C -> method3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    VALUE_D -> method4(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    else -> method5(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}
```

Can this be improved somehow to reduce code duplication? I imagine something like:

```kotlin
(if (isFooBar) method1 else method2)(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: Do the methods also return the same type of value?

Comment: They return `Unit`, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

If the methods all have the same return type and parameter types, you can first select the right method to call and assign that to a `val` like this, using the [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#function-references) syntax.

```
val methodToCall = 
    if (isFooBar) ::method1 else ::method2
    
methodToCall(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

In the case of `when`:

```
val methodToCall = when (someEnum) {
    A -> ::method1
    B -> ::method2
    C -> ::method3
    else -> ::method4
}
methodToCall(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Type inference will work correctly, provided that the methods do have the same parameter types and return types.

---

Technically, you don't need the `methodToCall` variable, and can just do:

```
(if (isFooBar) ::method1 else ::method2)(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

but I don't think this is very readable.